# Lore about Gibbeth

Tags: dnd-4e, lore

I am a big friend of solid background and since I read about the warlock in *[Wish Upon a Star](http://www.wizards.com/files/366_Warlocks.pdf)* from Dungeon Magazine 366, I am quite curious about the Star Pact and well... the stars. I am not very common with the books, so I searched the internet for Gibbeth the Green, the unnamed and so on. Problem was, I didn't find anything except 2-3 sentences about telling that he is green.

This leads me to my question: is there any lore/books/myth/content or information in general about Gibbeth out there which I can use?

Comment: Welcome to rpg.se! Please take a look at the [tour] and the [help]; they're a useful introduction to the site. I've modified your tags to connect this question with the right sort of experts (D&D 4e lore is mostly unrelated to the lore of other D&D editions, and Gibbeth isn't FR-specific). When you have 20+ rep, feel free to join the [chat]!

Comment: I did a little bit of editing to fiddle with wording, please make sure I didn't also introduce errors!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, this is the *start* of an answer and I'll add more if/when I find it. I'm going to mark it CW so that anyone who finds something additional can go ahead and add it.

Checking out the online compendium, we see two sources in Dungeon/Dragon magazine that look like they might be helpful. We also have several flavor text references to Gibbeth from warlock powers. I'll cover those in a moment. Let's take a look at the Dungeon Mag reference first. Issue 207 (can be found [here](http://archive.wizards.com/dnd/downloads/dungeon/207/Dungeon207Oct2012.pdf) starting on p3) has an adventure dealing with Gibbeth. Here's the first bit of lore:

> Gibbeth is a green star with an unknowable being
>   at its core. This being carries an eternal curse that
>   will drive everyone who sees its true form mad when
>   the end times come. A scion of Gibbeth is this being’s
>   presence made manifest in the world. An elderly
>   eladrin named Ilshaeren is the voice of Gibbeth, and
>   he leads the Order of the Endless Night.

There are several more bits of useful information scattered throughout the adventure such as:

> Ilshaeren is bent on learning Gibbeth’s true form.
>   He is wholly devoted to the menacing green star,
>   which (according to myth) reveals its true form
>   only at the end of the world.

The text also mentions that more can be found in Monster Manual 2. Something we should look into. The text is on page 197, but contains no real additional information from what I've already recorded here in the answer already.

Comment: Ummm. It may seem pedantic, but the question is asking for sources, not copy-pasting, and I think "ALL information about Gibbeth," even though there's not much, is kinda pushing our luck with the copyright gods. How about a summary with page citations?

Comment: @BESW trimmed the quotations down and ref'd the first page.

Comment: I am happy with every bit of information. Telling me that its in book xy would help me as well. I just want to avoid buying a book for 2 sentences Gibbeth. wax eagles answer helped me so far.

Comment: @bolgfred yeah, the *bulk* of the Gibbeth info so far is in that adventure from Dragon 207 if you can get ahold of that. MM2 only has a paragraph or two that won't tell you more than the dragon adventure I linked. I'll check MotP when I get home but I don't anticipate anything further there.